# PHP to Laravel loop conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to convert this PHP code:

```
    <?php
                    foreach ($arr as $v) {
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $v['bookTitle'] . '</td><td>';
                            $ar = array();
                            foreach ($v['authors'] as $key => $value) {
                            **$ar[] = '<a href="all?authorID=' . $key . '">' . $value . '</a>';**
                            }
                            echo implode(' , ', $ar) . '</td></tr>';
                    }

                    ?>
```

into Laravel code, but have problems

```
           @foreach ($arr as $v)
            <tr><td> {{ $v['bookTitle'] }}</td><td>
                <?php $ar = array(); ?>
                @foreach ($v['authors'] as $key => $value)
                    ***$ar[] = <a href="all?authorID=' . $key . '"> . $value . </a>;*** //{{ Html::link("all?authorID=  $key", "$value")}}

                 @endforeach
                {{implode(' , ', $ar)}}</td></tr>
             @endforeach
```

Can someone please help me with this?

```
 @foreach ($arr as $v)
                <tr><td> {{ $v['bookTitle'] }}</td><td>
                    @php $ar = array(); @endphp
                    @foreach ($v['authors'] as $key => $value)
                        @php  $ar[]; @endphp =  {{ Html::link("all?authorID=  $key", "$value")}}
                     @endforeach
                    {{implode(' , ', $ar)}}</td></tr>
                 @endforeach
```

FatalErrorException
Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: Could you post your full code, including the value of the arrays? Also, what's not working?

Comment: This is actually a table of books and authors. You can find all the books related to an author as well as co-authors by simply clicking on the author's name. I can't convert this $ar[] = '<a href="all?authorID=' . $key . '">' . $value . '</a>'; into Laravel so that it works within @foreach

Comment: So I want to implement a $variable into the @foreach loop without echoing it, just prepare it so that I can echo it after implode()

Comment: @cyberspacelogin what version of Laravel are you using? If you're on the latest then you could use the `@php [..] @endphp` and not rewrite it using blade until you re-factor to process the authors within your controller?

Comment: 5.4.27  Do you mean like this:(see above)

Comment: will try to implement a new function into the controller, thanks :) a lot

Comment: @cyberspacelogin Thanks for the version confirmation, i've added an answer to the question which elaborates on the usage of `@php`.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is at this line. The `$val` is not exist as your are make each object in loop to `$value` variable

```
$ar[] = <a href="all?authorID=' . $key . '"> . $val . </a>;
```

Secondly, the blade syntax is like below. Refer to [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops) for detail usage.

```
 @foreach ($v['authors'] as $key => $value)
     <td><a href="{{ url('all?authorID=' . $key) }}">{{ $value }}</a></td>

 @endforeach
```

Note: Please keep the long code in controller instead of `routes/web.php`

Comment: Thank you and you are right about the long code which should be in the controller, will have this fixed. But as you can see in my first comment above I already know on which line the mistake is, what I dont know is how to transform the working php raw code into laravel form- I want to implement an array key in the loop, so that I can fill the empty array and then emplode "," inbetween all keys.

Comment: Please disregard $val doesn't exist, this was a tippo, it's $value and I have also corrected it above

Comment: I dont think need to use array to store html and implode it. better to use the way the blade is design, even plain php also do the same thing to echo variable or value in the middle of html

Comment: As I am echoing authors, I dont want the last author to be followed by a ","too, just the previous ones. That is also the reason I dont use simple html in the loop. Probably I may have to use Eloquent fil() method, I am checking how :)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Larvel 5.4.x, you can simply do the following and not have to re-write it using blade:

```
@php
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $v['bookTitle'] . '</td><td>';
        $ar = array();
        foreach ($v['authors'] as $key => $value) {
            $ar[] = '<a href="all?authorID=' . $key . '">' . $value . '</a>';
        }
        echo implode(' , ', $ar) . '</td></tr>';
    }
@endphp
```

Albeit it's not the best solution, but, until you can move this logic into the controller and not have it within the view, it might be a good interim solution.

If you open up the following link for Control Structures within the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures and scroll down to the heading named "PHP" it should give you everything you need.

Comment: Thank you, if you say so, then I will leave it that way(will add only htmlspecialchars()), for now. Would like to also ask you why is this possible because of Larvel 5.4.x?